# Subsetting a table of two variables to remove the 0 values

Tags: r, subset

I have a table such as the following sample, which is obtained from a df (0==control; 1==case; heading figures are strata):

```
   208  209 210 211 212 213
0   4   16  3   5   2   0
1   0   7   2   0   6   2
```

I need to create a new df removing those strata with 0 cases (1) or controls (0).

So far, I created the following code which creates a vector with logicals:

```
table(df$status, df$strata)>0
```

but haven't managed to go further.

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example.  Do you want to remove the rows in 'df' based on the 'status' column 0 elements ?

Comment: `df[, colSums(df == 0) == 0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `subset`

```
subset(df, strata %in% dimnames(tbl)[[2]][colSums(tbl==0)==0])
#  status strata
#1       0    211
#5       1    209
#7       0    209
#8       1    208
#9       1    211
#10      0    208
```

I think the question is not about checking whether 'df' is equal to 0.   Infact, the OP wants to subset the dataset based on the frequency.

---

A compact option would be to use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(uniqueN(status)>1) .SD , by = .(strata)]
#    strata status
#1:    211      0
#2:    211      1
#3:    209      1
#4:    209      0
#5:    208      1
#6:    208      0
```

i.e. here we are converting the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'strata', `if` the `length` of the `unique` elements in 'status' is greater than 1 (in this case 2), we get the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`).

---

An option using the similar logic in `dplyr` is

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(strata) %>%
   filter(n_distinct(status)>1)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(status = sample(0:1, 10, replace=TRUE), 
           strata = sample(208:213, 10, replace = TRUE))

tbl <- table(df)
```

Comment: Subsetting using dimnames & colSums just worked for me. Any ideas how to confirm that I lost only the subjects I needed to? At the moment, I only could confirm the number of strata "lost" because of 0 frequence by using length(which(table(df$status, df$strata)==0))

Comment: @javivr I am not getting the confirmation part.  The logic applied (for the dplyr and data.table solutions) is if the length of unique elements in 'status' is greater than 1 after grouping by 'strata' we filter only those elements in the group that satisfy the condition.  So, isn't it kind of confirmation?

Comment: I guess the same logic would apply to using dimnames & colSums, right? If that´s the case, there is no need for confirmation. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @javivr Yes, the same logic applies as we are doing the `colSums` on a logical matrix and then checking whether it is 0.